# How sensitive is ML-estimation of the expected value if the covariance matrix is not correct?

Tags: st.statistics, oc.optimization-and-control

Suppose, we have a random variable $Y \sim \mathrm{N}\left( Ax, \, \Sigma \right)$ and realisations $y$. I would like to estimate $x$, the parameter of the expected value.
The loglikelihood function is $$L(x) =- \frac{1}{2} \left[ \ln \left( \left| \Sigma \right| \right) + \left( y - Ax \right)^T \left( \Sigma \right)^{-1} \left( y - Ax \right) + k \ln(2 \pi) \right],$$ 
thus 
$$D_L(x) = \left( y - Ax \right)^T \left( \Sigma \right)^{-1} A,$$ which leads to $$\hat{x} = \left[ A^T \left( \Sigma \right)^{-1} A \right]^{-1} A^T \left( \Sigma \right)^{-1}y,$$ since the covariance matrix is self-adjoint.

My question is now: What happens if a small error matrix $E$ is added to $\Sigma$? Is there anything I can say about the sensitivity apart from giving the formula 
$$\hat{x}_E = \left[ A^T \left(\Sigma +E\right)^{-1} A \right]^{-1} A^T \left( \Sigma+E \right)^{-1}y?$$
Probably, this was already done but I did not find any sources dealing with this problem in particular. I was thinking about the analyzing the eigenvalues. Is there any other way? Are there any sources you recommend?

Comment: Is $A$ square here?

Comment: No, it is not a square.

Comment: It seems that you can write down a first-order expression for the perturbation in $y$ without using eigenvalues, just the first-order expansion of the inverse of a matrix, $(\Sigma+E)^{-1} = \Sigma^{-1} + \Sigma^{-1}E\Sigma^{-1}+O(\|E\|^2)$. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to quantify $\| \hat{x} - \hat{x}_E \|$. Your answer concerning $(\Sigma + E)^{-1}$ seems helpful (thanks!) but I do not know how the error propagates when inverting $(A^T (\Sigma + E) A)$.

Comment: It's just the same formula: you are inverting $A^T\Sigma^{-1}A$ plus a first-order perturbation of $A^T\Sigma^{-1}E\Sigma^{-1}A$, which gives $(A^T\Sigma^{-1}A)^{-1}A^T\Sigma^{-1}E\Sigma^{-1}A(A^T\Sigma^{-1}A)^{-1}$.

Comment: It looks very helpful to me, great! I will think about it. Thank you very much!